# Can not connect to admin channel with java application

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am new to MQ and I am using this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq) with the default setting.
I need to connect through a java application (but without websphere).

I use the admin account to connect to the DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN channel and i get the following error :

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

How can i manage to connect with the admin user ?

Comment: Look at the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG for info on the cause of the 2035.  Edit and add to your question of you need further help.

Comment: Are you supplying the user id and password that you configured on the docker image?