# Cannot create temporary queue with default app user

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am new to MQ and I am using this [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq) with the default setting.
I need to connect through a java application (but without websphere).

I use the **app** user. This one can connect to the "DEV.APP.SVRCONN" channel without problem but i need to create a temporary queue (in order to get a response) and it fail to create it with the following error :

```
JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'
```

Cause by this error :

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

I checked with the MQ Manager and the "SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE" does not exist, should i need to create it ?

Comment: Is this really a distinct question from https://stackoverflow.com/q/69344838/1968?

Comment: For me this 2 différent problem so 2 different question can be asked

Comment: Did you create the default objects or not? See docker instructions about env vars say about MQ_DEV - Set this to false to stop the default objects being created.

Comment: How did you check for the SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE.  this should exist.   The error indicates you are missing permission to the queue, if it didn't exist you would get 2085 MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME, unless the 2035 is related to the queue Manger not the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Default developer configuration](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/docs/developer-config.md), users in `mqclient` group (which will be what you are using) have been given access to all queues and topics starting with `DEV.**` and have `put`, `get`, `pub`, `sub`, `browse` and `inq` permissions.

You are trying to use a queue that does not start with `DEV.**` so you will first need to set appropriate authority for the users in the `mqclient` group to do this. They will also need `dsp` authority in order to create a temporary queue from a model.

```
SET AUTHREC GROUP('mqclient') OBJTYPE(QUEUE) PROFILE(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE)    AUTHADD(GET,PUT,DSP)
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem

Comment: @Jib'z - happy to hear that solved your problem. If the answer was what you needed, click on the tick to accept it.